# Separate json from html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm beginning to use html charts to display data coming from `json` files. Up until five days ago, I very rarely did anything with html charts. But now that's all I do.

So I'm using an `anychart` chart, and I've been trying to find a way to populate the chart with a 'json` file.

After much trial-error, I was able to *somewhat* separate the data and move it to a `json` file. The problem is that the file's not completely `json` string.

As you can see, *MyFile.json* has the `json` string and some chart components. I would like my json file to be only json data; everything else should be in the html, another javascript, or anywhere else. But it cannot be in the `json` file.

In other words, *MyFile.json* should only include this:

> {"x": "January","value": 10000},{"x": "February","value": 12000}, {"x": "March","value": 18000}]

Is this possible? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Here's *MyFile.json*:

```
{
    "chart": {
        "type": "line",
        "series": [{
            "seriesType": "spline",
            "data": [{
                "x": "January",
                "value": 10000
            }, {
                "x": "February",
                "value": 12000
            }, {
                "x": "March",
                "value": 18000
            }]
        }],
        "container": "container"
    }
}
```

And here's my `html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/7.13.1/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/css/latest/anychart-ui.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('MyFile.json', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            anychart.fromJson(data).draw();
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I cannot see any other data in in the json file

Comment: I think OP means stuff like "type": "line" and probably anything that's not in the data array, ie the presentation parts.

Comment: You can use jquery data to link the json to the table. $('#container').data('series', data.chart.series). And then retrieve it var series=$('#container').data('series')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly... There might be a way within Anycharts to do this in a better way (like assign an object as the "settings" then assign a different one wit the "data"), but here's one way that you could implement this yourself:

JSON file:

```
[{
  "x": "January",
  "value": 10000
}, {
  "x": "February",
  "value": 12000
}, {
  "x": "March",
  "value": 18000
}]
```

AJAX request in javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('MyFile.json', function(data) {
        var wrapper = {
          "chart": {
            "type": "line",
            "series": [{
              "seriesType": "spline",
              "data": data // adding the ajax response data
            }],
            "container": "container"
          }
        };
        anychart.fromJson(wrapper).draw();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can embed json data in a html element using `data-*` attributes.

Comment: I do not want to embed json data in the html. I want to separate it completely from the html.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to append each chart into the container first and then set jquery data with the series.

```
    $.getJSON('MyFile.json', function (charts) {
    for (var i = 0, len = charts.length; i < len; i++) {
        $('#container').append('<div id="chart_' + i + '"></div>');
        $('chart_' + i).data('series', charts[i].series.data);
    }
});
```